# Weird Light Artifact, Render with EEVEE

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I get a weird artifact when working with EEVEE, and it seems to be related to how my mesh distorts with the use of some modifiers.

I see this happening often, has anyone also see this kind of anomaly?

[image]